# mysql not receiving all data

Tags: php, mysql

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (orderID, Imie, Nazwisko, Email, UlicaINumer, KodPocztowy, Miasto) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$orderID = uniqid();
$Imie = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$Nazwisko = isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : "";
$Email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
$UlicaINumer = isset($_POST['street']) ? $_POST['street'] : "";

$KodPocztowy = isset($_POST['postal_code']) ? $_POST['postal_code'] : "";
$Miasto = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : "";

$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $orderID, $Imie, $Nazwisko, $Email, $UlicaINumer, $KodPocztowy, $Miasto);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```

I basically wanted for this to take the input text from forms in other file, form looks like this:

```
<form action="polaczenie.php" method="POST">

<label for="name">Imię:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-input" required>

<label for="surname">Nazwisko:</label>
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" class="form-input" required>

<label for="email">E-mail:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-input" required>

<label for="street">Ulica i numer:</label>
<input type="text" id="street" name="street" class="form-input" required>

<label for="postal_code">Kod pocztowy:</label>
<input type="text" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" class="form-input" required>

<label for="city">Miasto:</label>
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form-input" required>
```

For some reason in mysql database I can only see the `uniqeID`, it doesn't take any data from forms, could someone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Don't put each line as a separate code block, it's very hard to read! You can [edit] your question. And see also [ask] - we can't run your code or debug it, you need to provide a clear problem statement and a [mre] of the issue. At a guess, you're running the insert before the form has been submitted, because there's no code to check the form status or whether it's a POST request or not before proceeding with the insert

Comment: Sounds like POST is not being set for some reason. Is this a standard form or does this submit via JS? `orderID` should likely be auto-increment